# Display one colour option on Shopify product page

Tags: colors, shopify, product, liquid, variant

I'm trying to display only one colour variant of my product at any time when one is selected.

I can get it to work when I manually assign an image to each of the product colours, but when I upload a new .CSV, this is overwritten. Since there are going to be hundreds of products on this store, this isn't a viable solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Link to .CSV**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1trq0X3MjR-n2THFnT8gYYlwKscnQavCeeZ8L-ifYaHw/edit?usp=sharing

**Link to Product page**

https://tomgarrad.myshopify.com/products/lightweight-trainers?variant=37878137356461

Comment: There is a password on the store, would you mind sharing it so I could take a look?

Comment: Please see below a pastebin to all of the code I've edited - If you need anything else, just let me know or I can give you access. **product-template.liquid** https://pastebin.com/Bt7VxTKZ  **theme.js** https://pastebin.com/MnkMEWeA

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Shopify API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api) instead of uploading from a spreadsheet. It allows you to do a lot of things, the following code would upload a product:

```
POST /admin/api/2021-01/products.json
{
  "product": {
    "title": "Lightweight Trainers",
    "body_html": "<strong>Great trainers!</strong>", #Description
    "vendor": "Tom", #The name of the products vendor
    "product_type": "Trainer",
    "variants": [
      {
        "option1": "Blue",
        "price": "10.00",
        "sku": "123" #code
      },
      {
        "option2": "Red",
        "price": "10.00",
        "sku": "123" 
      }
    ],
    "images": [
      {
        "attachment": "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==\n"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The image attachment is [base64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) so keep that in mind when uploading images. Shopify has a very detailed documentation of their API and it's easy to [setup](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/getting-started). Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Insula - I'm looking for only the blue images to display when the blue variant is selected, and same with the red images when red is selected. Essentially to hide any thumbnails/images of any colour variant that isn't currently selected. If that helps at all?

Comment: Ah so you want the display image to first be blue, with the blue variant selected. Then if a user selects red, it'll display the image for red? If so let me write up some code for you and i'll edit my answer when i'm done

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you.

Comment: I should mention that it would also display the blue thumbnails when the blue colour variant is selected and hide the red thumbnails. And vice versa when red is selected. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much @Insula - I would have trouble with selecting the alt image for each variant, if that's what you're suggesting in step 1, as every time I upload a new CSV, these are erased; and since I have hundreds products, I won't be able to do this every time. I do have image alt text in the CSV already using the text as the colour name, is that sufficient? I will go through your steps shortly, thank you again.

Comment: So if you add your alt text to the images it's all erased? If so, I think you could use the [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/) to help you upload all these products at once.

Comment: The Image alt text is okay, it's just the manually selected images in the products page that get removed. I think that's fine, I just thought it was worth mentioning. I'll let you know if I can get this working soon

Comment: if the image alt text is fine, then in theory it should still link to the variant selected. If what I wrote isn't working for you, notify me and i'll find something else to try to help

Comment: Thank you for your instructions - I've tried them but unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried something similar before and it would seem that this only works when you have a featured image manually selected for each colour variant.

Comment: hm okay. Have you tried using the [Shopify API](https://shopify.dev/concepts/shopify-introduction)? Apologies, before I linked the Spotify API. You can upload multiple products using the API, I can help you if you would like

Comment: Unfortunately my client is very insistent on uploading/updating products via .CSV - I'm looking into CSS fixes that might be able to hide the additional thumbnails with the code you've written in place but not getting very far.

Comment: I think you should ask this on the [Shopify community](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Community/ct-p/en) they might be able to figure out a solution to this. Sorry I couldn't help mate

Comment: No worries - Thank you very much for you help though, I appreciate it.